# Set Block Status from xml and show if its enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, product, tabs, cms-block

Created `CMS > Block` and display it on product page as tabs following [this](http://twincreations.co.uk/add-custom-product-tab-in-magento-1-9-ce/) tutorial

**app/design/frontend/[theme]/default/layout/catalog.xml**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.sizes" as="sizes" template="catalog/product/view/sizes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Size Guide</value></action>
</block>
```

From the above code, block title is set from admin and it will be shown as product tab even if its disabled from admin end.

1. How can we show block only if its enabled from admin and check using
   some `IF` condition in xml ?

Also is it possible to show the title given from admin end rather than setting it from `XML` file ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do it via XML. But modifying .phtml file you surely can show/hide the Tabs.

File to edit:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/[your-theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

And update the following block of code:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <!-- Edit Starts -->
                <?php
                if ($alias == 'sizes') {
                    $shouldHideSizeTab = false; # @todo add some condition on which it will hide
                    if ($shouldHideSizeTab) {
                        continue; # escapes size tab
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <!-- Edit Ends -->
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The tab should hide if status is diabled from admin. How can I implement in aobve code ?

Comment: What's the path (xml) to your settings?